# Cross platform home path or conditional platform-specific path?

Tags: nuget, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

So the problem I'm trying to solve here is, now that visual studio is cross platform, I have to rethink some build strategies. At the moment, I have my nuget library project publish packages to a local feed after a build. This allows me to develop in other projects that use these package without having to publish to the remote nuget server. Currently, I facilitate this by adding the following target to each respective project's csproj:

```
<Target Name="PushPackage" AfterTargets="Pack" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
    <Exec Command="nuget init $(ProjectDir)\bin\debug C:\nuget" />
</Target>
```

So this pushes each package to c:\nuget. This works fine on windows, but when an individual is working in VSCode on Ubuntu, for example, `C:\` isn't a thing.

So my question is this: is there cross-platform way to target "home" for example? I considered using `$(Platform)` as a condition for the Exec line in the target so that I could just issue a different command using a condition, but I can't seem to find a listing of what values I can expect from `$(Platform)`. Any other ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cross platform home path or conditional platform-specific path?

If you want this command can be used across platforms, you can use the option **$(OS)** with condition **'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT'** and **'$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT'**

So the detail target should be:

```
  <Target Name="PushPackageOnWindows" AfterTargets="Pack" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug' AND '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT'">
    <Exec Command="nuget init $(ProjectDir)\bin\debug C:\nuget" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="PushPackageOnUbuntu" AfterTargets="Pack" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug' AND '$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT'">
    <Exec Command="nuget command on Ubuntu" />
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

I accepted the answer above but I wanted to offer the final solution in case someone else came across this same case. The .deb nuget package was way out of date and the `dotnet nuget` cli command is super watered down, so I ended up installing mono and downloading the latest windows nuget.exe. It wasn't executing when it did it as two separate target blocks, so I used it like so:

```
 <Target Name="PushPackage" AfterTargets="Pack">    
    <Exec Condition="'$(OS)'=='Windows_NT'" 
      Command="nuget init $(ProjectDir)\bin\Debug c:\nuget" />
    <Exec Condition="'$(OS)'!='Windows_NT'" 
      Command="mono /usr/bin/nuget.exe init $(ProjectDir)bin/Debug ~/Documents/Nuget" />
 </Target>
```